# React loops over array map only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to generate a table in react and I want to take the data from firebase and put it in a json and pass that to the main file

```
  var dummy = [
       {'name':'shoe','remark':'remark','price':'price','photo':'photo','amount':'350',},
   
   ]
   var ref = db.ref("users/random/cart");
   ref.once("value")
   .then( function(snapshot) {
     var snapshot_value = snapshot.val();
   var this_is_an_example = {'name':'shoe','remark':'remark','price':'price','photo':'photo','amount':'350'};
       dummy.push(this_is_an_example)
       ref.off();
   
   });
   export default dummy;
```

In the main file if I console.log() I get [image]

Now this is the map :

```
dummy.map((data) => {
console.log('data here', data)
```

[image]
})

[[image]]

It iterates once then throws this error
I do not think that the table error is the reason why it iterates only once because the error is thrown even when I only have one element in array

Here is the full code for the table

```
              <ClientTable>
               <thead>
               <ClientTr>
                   <ClientTh>Item Name</ClientTh>
                   <ClientTh>Remark</ClientTh>
                   <ClientTh>Price</ClientTh>
                   <ClientTh>Quantity</ClientTh>
                   <ClientTh>Amount</ClientTh>
                   <ClientTh>Edit</ClientTh>
               </ClientTr>
               </thead>
                   <tbody>
                   {dummy.map((data, key) => {
                       console.log('one', data)
                       return (
                           
                           <ClientTr key={'key'}>
                               <ClientTd>
                                   <Wrapper>
   
                                       <ProductWrapper>
                                           <ImageWrapper src={Product} alt="product" />
                                       </ProductWrapper>
                                       {data.name}
                                   </Wrapper>
                               </ClientTd>
                               <ClientTd>
                                   {data.remark}
                               </ClientTd>
                               <ClientTd>
                                   {data.price}
                               </ClientTd>
                               <ClientTd>
                                   <NumberBox />
                               </ClientTd>
                               <ClientTd>
                                   {data.amount}
                               </ClientTd>
                               <ClientTd>
                                   Delete
                               </ClientTd>
                           </ClientTr>
   
                       );
   
                   })}
                   </tbody>
               </ClientTable>
```

Comment: That is not an issue with the map but your table formatting.

Comment: So, the error has nothing to do with the iteration/table, if i make the array empty and push the data from firebase it doesn't work, so the problem is from my firebase function @JoelHager

Comment: error message has been already explained, your tr tag should in tbody. <table><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: tried it already, it does  not solve my issue @wenzi

Comment: The error is explicitly stating that the table formatting is incorrect.

Comment: @JoelHager I have added my code for the table

Comment: First of all, it is the warning, not an error, and @JoelHager is right about that, this is about the formatting of the table not the firebase function issue.

Comment: Bruh, nope I have solved the warning

Answer (score 1):

See ClientTr is the Direct child of ClientTable, and the issue says tr can't be the direct child of the table, tr can appear as child of thead, tbody or tfoot. So your ClientTr contains headers, just put it inside the thead and the issue will be resolved.

Comment: I did that but again that error is not what I am trying to solve, now that error is solved but is not what I want, there is a problem with my firebase function

Comment: Can you please show the error

Comment: there is no error,

Comment: ```ref.once("value")
.then( function(snapshot) {
  var snapshot_value = snapshot.val();
  var feed = {'namea':'shoe','remarka':'remarka','pricea':'pricea','photoa':'photo','amoaunt':'350'};
    dummy.push(feed)
    console.log(dummy)
    ref.off();

});``` this is my firebase code I need to take the feed and push it in a external json var

Comment: dummy variable is an array, so you are pushing another JSON object to the array, dummy already have one JSON object, after pushing the second object, you logged the value in the console and it is showing two objects, it looks fine, so what you want to achieve then.

Comment: it is showing 2 but when I map the array it iterates over it just once but there are 2 elements in it

Comment: Oops, maybe you are confusing something, sometimes console just increases the number if we log the same output multiple times, try to put 2 different objects, and then see.

Comment: so if i make another array and push the firebase json in it, it loads the data in it but the map refuses to iterate over it, again as I said it is a problem with how I store the data from firebase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245839/discussion-between-muhammad-aamir-and-like-who).